# aligning and stacking a divs

Tags: css, html, alignment

I apologize if the question isn't phrased correctly or clear. Let me explain.

**I have 4 divs inside the middle div. Is meant to look like below:**

```
 --------------  -----------   -------------
|custExpBox    || techSumBox| |escalationBox|
 -------------  |           |  -------------
 -------------- |           |
|workaroundnBox||           |
 -------------   -----------
```

**But instead i get:**

```
 -------------   -----------   -------------
|custExpBox    || techSumBox| |escalationBox|
 -------------  |           |  -------------
                |           |
                |           |
 -------------  -----------
|workaroundBox|
 -------------
```

**Here's a stripped down version of html code code:**

```
<div id="middle">
    <div id="custExpBox"></div>          
    <div id="techSumBox">  </div>
    <div id="escalationBox"> </div>
    <div id="workaroundBox"> </div>
</div>
```

**CSS code:**

```
#middle{

    width:100%;
    margin-top:16px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px dashed black;
}

#custExpBox{

    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    width:40%;
    background-color:#EAF2D3;
    line-height:17px;
    padding:3px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:scroll;

}

#techSumBox{

    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    width:30%;
    background-color:#EAF2D3;
    line-height:17px;
    padding:4px;
    height:406px;
    overflow:scroll;
    border:1px solid black;
    overflow:auto;
}

#escalationBox{

    margin-top:16px;
    display: inline-block;
    float:right; 
    width:18%;
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color:#E9EBA9;
    line-height:17px;
    border-radius:5px;  
    padding:4px;
}

#workaroundBox{
   display: inline-block;
   float:left;
   width:40%;
   background-color:#EAF2D3;
   line-height:17px;
   padding:3px;
   height:198px;
   overflow:scroll;
   margin-top:6px;  
}
```

Appreciate the help. thanks!

**EDIT 1**:
Thought I'd let you know that if I change the height of techSumBox div to the same size as custExpBox it appears as desired. The issue is when the height is greater than the custExpBox div.

Comment: Re: EDIT 1, this is the case because `workaroundBox` will get cleared to the left if `techSumBox` and `custExpBox` are the same height. Still recommend wrapping the divs.

Comment: Multiple solutions provided. Why no acceptable answers?

Comment: @JSuar: Cos i'm super busy at work :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT 1**

[This solution](http://jsfiddle.net/rn9Mx/) does not require a wrapper div. Maybe this will work better for you.

The HTML just needs to be rearranged and the CSS updated.

HTML

```
<div id="middle">
    <div id="escalationBox">escalationBox</div>
    <div id="custExpBox">custExpBox</div>
    <div id="workaroundBox">workaroundBox</div>    
    <div id="techSumBox">techSumBox</div>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
#middle{

    width:100%;
    margin-top:16px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px dashed black;
}

#custExpBox{

    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    width:40%;
    background-color:#EAF2D3;
    line-height:17px;
    padding:3px;
    height:50px;
    overflow:scroll;

}

#techSumBox{

    width:30%;
    background-color:#EAF2D3;
    line-height:17px;
    padding:4px;
    height:300px;
    overflow:scroll;
    border:1px solid black;
    overflow:auto;
}


#escalationBox{

    margin-top:16px;
    float:right;
    width:18%;
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color:#E9EBA9;
    line-height:17px;
    border-radius:5px;  
    padding:4px;
}

#workaroundBox{
   display: inline-block;
   float:left;
   clear:left;
   width:40%;
   background-color:#EAF2D3;
   line-height:17px;
   padding:3px;
   height:198px;
   overflow:scroll;
   margin-top:6px;  
}​
```

**EDIT 0**

This [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/HFPF9/1/) resembles your ascii example. The two left divs just required `width:100%;` to span the entired left div container.

---

If you combine the two divs on the left you can obtain the desired result. Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/HFPF9/.

So, a new div containing the two left divs:

HTML

```
<div id="Left">
    <div id="custExpBox">custExpBox</div>          
    <div id="workaroundBox">workaroundBox </div>        
</div>
```

CSS

```
#Left {
    float:left;
    width:40%;
}
```

Then `workaroundBox` will need to `clear: left;` in order to stack correctly.

**All Code**

HTML

```
<div id="middle">
    <div id="custworkHolder">
        <div id="custExpBox">1</div>
         <div id="workaroundBox">2</div> 
    </div>
    <div id="techSumBox">3</div>
    <div id="escalationBox">4</div>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
#middle{
    width:100%;
    margin-top:16px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px dashed black;
}

#Left {
    float:left;
    width:40%;
}

#custExpBox{
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#EAF2D3;
    line-height:17px;
    padding:3px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:scroll;
}


#techSumBox{
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    width:30%;
    background-color:#EAF2D3;
    line-height:17px;
    padding:4px;
    height:406px;
    overflow:scroll;
    border:1px solid black;
    overflow:auto;
}


#escalationBox{

    margin-top:0px;
    display: inline-block;
    float:right; 
    width:25%;
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color:#E9EBA9;
    line-height:17px;
    border-radius:5px;  
    padding:4px;
}

#workaroundBox{
   display: inline-block;
   float:left;
   clear: left;
   width:100%;
   background-color:#EAF2D3;
   line-height:17px;
   padding:3px;
   height:198px;
   overflow:scroll;
   margin-top:6px;  
}​
```

Comment: Provided multiple solutions. No reasons provided for down vote.

Answer (score 2):

What you should do is consider wrapping the two elements which are stacked in the left column in their own div. Ensure that the wrapping div has a proper width definition. Then remove the floats and define each containing div as inline-block. Next, ensure that the right two columns are vertically aligned to the top.

This is probably what you are after: http://jsfiddle.net/y75Fc/

html:

```
<div id="middle">
 <div id="custworkHolder">
  <div id="custExpBox">1</div>
  <div id="workaroundBox">2</div> 
 </div>
 <div id="techSumBox">3</div>
 <div id="escalationBox">4</div>
</div>​
```

css:

```
#middle{
 width:100%;
 margin-top:16px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 border:1px dashed black;
}

#custworkHolder
{
 width:40%;
 display:inline-block;
}

#custExpBox{
 background-color:#EAF2D3;
 line-height:17px;
 padding:3px;
 height:200px;
 overflow:scroll;
}

#workaroundBox{
 background-color:#EAF2D3;
 line-height:17px;
 padding:3px;
 height:198px;
 overflow:scroll;
 margin-top:6px;  
}

#techSumBox{
 vertical-align:top;
 display:inline-block;
 width:30%;
 background-color:#EAF2D3;
 line-height:17px;
 padding:4px;
 height:406px;
 overflow:scroll;
 border:1px solid black;
 overflow:auto;
}

#escalationBox{
 vertical-align:top;
 display:inline-block;
 margin-top:16px;
 width:18%;
 border:1px solid black;
 background-color:#E9EBA9;
 line-height:17px;
 border-radius:5px;  
 padding:4px;
}
```

​

Comment: There are other solutions that do not require a wrapper div.

Answer (score 1):

All the elements are floated to the left and `workaroudbox` is the last one so when it wraps it positions itself at the bottom, expected behavior. Think of it as stacking them to the left one on top of the other, they just can't overlap, no matter the height.
Here you have the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kxYna/). I just added the `#dummy` div and floated it to the left.

### Update

[New fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kxYna/1/).

### New Update

Code:

HTML:

```
    <div id="middle">
        <div id="dummy">            
            <div id="custExpBox"></div>          
            <div id="workaroundBox"> </div>
        </div>
        <div id="techSumBox">  </div>
        <div id="escalationBox"> </div>
    </div>​
```

CSS:

```
    #dummy{float:left;}

    #middle{
        width:100%;
        margin-top:16px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        display:inline-block;
        border:1px dashed black;
    }
    #custExpBox{
        display: inline-block;
        float:left;
        width:80px;
        background-color:#EAF2D3;
        line-height:17px;
        padding:3px;
        height:100px;
        overflow:scroll;
        background-color: red;
    }
    #techSumBox{
        display: inline-block;
        float:left;
        width:80px;
        background-color:#EAF2D3;
        line-height:17px;
        padding:4px;
        height:180px;
        overflow:scroll;
        border:1px solid black;
        overflow:auto;
        background-color: blue;
    }
    #escalationBox{
        display: inline-block;
        float:left; 
        width:40px;
        height: 60px;
        border:1px solid black;
        background-color:#E9EBA9;
        padding:4px;
        background-color: green;
    }
    #workaroundBox{
       display: inline-block;
       float:left;
       width:80px;
       background-color:#EAF2D3;
       line-height:17px;
       padding:3px;
       height:50px;
       overflow:scroll;
       background-color: cyan;
       clear: both;
    }​
```

Comment: I updated the fiddle, just changed the percentages for pixels and added some colors to make make it clearer. I don`t really think this is worth downvoting.

Comment: You should include code in the answer itself rather than just including a link to JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution it's wrapping the floated `divs`. Take a look at [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdiaz/4TSfD/).